In PyTorch how do I compute the gradient of a matrix multiplication with respect to the hidden state inside the forward pass?
Here is a simplified version of the model I am working on:
class InferContextModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, context_size, output_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.context_size = context_size
        self.embedding_size = input_size
        self.output_size = output_size

        self.alpha = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(1.0, dtype=torch.float32))
        self.linear_layer = nn.Linear(self.output_size, self.embedding_size)
        self.previous_input = None

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size, device):
        return torch.zeros(batch_size, self.context_size, device=device)

    def recurrence(self, input, hidden):
        context.requires_grad_(True)
        
        if self.previous_input is not None:
            prev_prediction = self.linear(self.previous_input)
            loss = 0.5 * torch.sum((prev_prediction - input) ** 2)
            hidden_grad = torch.autograd.grad(loss, hidden, retain_graph=False)[0]
            
            # Update context without requiring gradients
            with torch.no_grad():
                hidden = hidden - self.alpha * hidden_grad.detach()
                hidden = hidden.detach()

            
        self.previous_input = input.detach()
        return self.output_layer(hidden), hidden

    def forward(self, input, context=None, num_steps=1):
        batch_size = input.shape[1]
        seq_len = input.size(0)
        outputs = torch.empty(
            seq_len, 
            batch_size, 
            self.vocab_size, 
            device=input.device
        )
        
        if context is None:
            context = self.init_hidden(batch_size, input.device)
        
        for i in range(seq_len):
            output = None
            for _ in range(num_steps):
                output, context = self.recurrence(input[i], context)
            outputs[i] = output
        
        return outputs, context

Obviously this model doesn't make much sense, but I don't think the complexity that makes the model function is required to address the bug I can't get past. When I run the model I get the error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/geode2/home/u040/joshnunl/BigRed200/projects_with_transformers/project5_main.py", line 327, in <module>
    losses = estimate_loss(model, eval_iters, train_data, val_data,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/N/u/joshnunl/BigRed200/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 116, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/geode2/home/u040/joshnunl/BigRed200/projects_with_transformers/utils.py", line 44, in estimate_loss
    logits, loss = model(X.T, Y)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/N/u/joshnunl/BigRed200/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1553, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/N/u/joshnunl/BigRed200/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1562, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/geode2/home/u040/joshnunl/BigRed200/projects_with_transformers/models/Context_RNN.py", line 195, in forward
    logits, context = self.rnn(x)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/N/u/joshnunl/BigRed200/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1553, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/N/u/joshnunl/BigRed200/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1562, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/geode2/home/u040/joshnunl/BigRed200/projects_with_transformers/models/Context_RNN.py", line 151, in forward
    output, context = self.recurrence(input[i], context)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/geode2/home/u040/joshnunl/BigRed200/projects_with_transformers/models/Context_RNN.py", line 116, in recurrence
    context_grad = torch.autograd.grad(loss, context, retain_graph=False)[0]
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/N/u/joshnunl/BigRed200/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 436, in grad
    result = _engine_run_backward(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/N/u/joshnunl/BigRed200/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/autograd/graph.py", line 768, in _engine_run_backward
    return Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

What I want to do should be relatively simple. I just want to find the gradient with respect to the hidden state, but I don't want the hidden state to be updated as a part of the model parameters. Any suggestions?
I have made multiple attempts to solve this issue with multiple sota LLMs and have not come up with a working solution.

In your recurrence method, the loss tensor is unrelated to hidden at all so no gradient can be computed. The way your recurrence work, hidden is used to compute output but will never be related to previous_input since this is always equal to input[i].  I imagine you actually want to call recurrence with output as argument, is that correct ?
